# What does <.ctor> mean when it appears in a symbol in .Net

Tags: .net, symbols

I have a symbol that appears that is listed as

```
MyNamespace.MyClass.<.ctor>b__8()
```

What exactly does the `<.ctor>` mean? Or the `b__8()` for that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This member is a method generated by C#'s compiler for a lambda expression or anonymous delegate used in `MyClass`'s constructor. The part in `<>` is the name of the method where the lambda expression/anonymous delegate was seen, and `b__8` is just a meaningless suffix to make the method name unique.

**NB:** this naming scheme is an internal implementation detail of C#'s compiler. Don't rely on it if you can help it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the <.ctor> simply is the constructor. The b__8() represents a lamba in that method.